# Tamper HTML request with Userscript

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I developed a user script for debugging purposes. Its goal is to enabled debugging features in my app when the user script is enabled.

My app includes a JavaScript library that I developed. I also have an alternative build of this library that contains extra debugging features.

How could I use my user script to make my app request the debug version of the library instead of the normal one? I'm looking for a way to tamper the HTTP request so that everything looks the same from the client side, but the library code that is returned is different.

Edit:
I could just replace the `<script>` tag but the script i'm trying to replace is added dynamically by creating a new `<script>` tag in runtime... How would I intercept that just in time?

Answer (score 0):

Just create the script and add it to the page, it should overwrite the existing one.

```
(function(callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("src", "//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js");
  script.addEventListener('load', callback);
  document.body.appendChild(script);
})

// main codez go in here
(function(){
  window.alert($('a').length+" Links");
});
```

Just replace "//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" with your own script.

Comment: Hm that's a good idea. But it will be unreliable in my case because the script I want to replace is already injected in this same way! I'll update my question. Thank you.

Comment: But your answer was not useless. It gave me an idea and I just found about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver so I might be able to create the script tag and then list to mutations to that tag